# How to get user with no alternate email address Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Im trying to get all the users with no alternate email address assigned on Azure AD.

Using Powershell I got this 2 options but seems this is not the correct way:

Option 1 $AllUsers = Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.AlternateEmailAddresses -eq $null};

Option 2 $AllUsers = Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.AlternateEmailAddresses -eq @()};

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `$_.AlternateEmailAddresses.count -eq 0`.

```
Get-MsolUser -All | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,AlternateEmailAddresses | where {$_.AlternateEmailAddresses.count -eq 0};
```

[image]